# is there any ble api in Ndk

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, java-native-interface, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can we use Ble hardware(Bluetooth low energy) direct from Ndk without any java interface.

I am new to NDk. So I don't know about jni, or Ndk.

I want to control the bluetooth hardware directly from native code ,

Answer (score 3):

NO and YES.

NO: There is no BLE **API** in ndk.

YES: You can talk to BT hardware from C code.

In AOSP, look under `<>/hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/`
there are a bunch of headers.

bluetooth.h defines the interface for Android's bluetooth module. Bluedroid implements it.

You could load bluedroid module in your process, and call the interface methods directly from your code.

You'd need to ensure no other process is loading this module to ensure that your process gets full access to BT hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Cloud you please explain the above because  I am new to ndk.

1. How can i get these ?
2. How will the interface work?
3. Is there any problem while doing it?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. There's a lot of things that happen before and after Android chooses to call these functions. Only problem is that it doesn't make any sense to call these functions directly, unless you've written a BT stack and are testing it.