# Change BLE advertising appearance of a phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to set the Appearance of an android smartphone to a "HID Keyboard". So the first 4 Bytes in my Raw-Data should look like this:

> {0x03, 0x19, 0xC1, 0x03}
>
> 0x03 -> Size of 3 Bytes
>
> 0x19 -> Appearance (see:
>   https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile)
>
> 0xC1 & 0x03 -> 961 HID-Keyboard (see:
>   https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/documentation/nrf51/4.4.0/html/group___b_l_e___a_p_p_e_a_r_a_n_c_e_s.html)

But when I use the AdvertiseData class from the android SDK, I have only 3 options to add Data:

```
addManufacturerData(), addServiceData() & addServiceUuid()
```

Is there a way to set / manipulate the raw advertising data?

thank you

Comment: I think it's not possible, since the Java API only offers the functions you already mentioned. Someone said that you can access the native BLE api with in c code, which may offer more opportunities, but I doubt if it's really possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036107/is-there-any-ble-api-in-ndk

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was afraid of. Seems like I have to find another solution.